# Ubuntu.sh on Android Phone

Tags: android, ubuntu-for-android

So today I noticed something weird on my phone. I used a terminal emulator to see what I could do with it, and noticed that there is a file called ubuntu.sh. I tried to run it and got all sorts of permission denied errors, and then I decided to root my phone. But now I'm nervous to run it, does anyone know what it does or why it is there?

*edit*
I forgot to mention that I have an AT&T Morotola Atrix 4G running Android 2.3.6. Also when I use the app SSHDroid to go into my phone from my Ubuntu machine, I'm greeted with this:

"The programs included with the Ubuntu system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Ubuntu comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by
applicable law.

To access official Ubuntu documentation, please visit:
http://help.ubuntu.com/"

Also, here are the contents of ubuntu.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib:/usr/local/lib

# make sure no left-over pidfiles, etc.
#######################################
rm -fr /var/run/*
rm -fr /var/lock/*

chmod 666 /system/usr/keychars/*
rm -f /tmp/tab*
mkdir -p /home/adas/Desktop
chmod 755 /home/adas/Desktop
chown -R adas.adas /home/adas/Desktop
[ -x /usr/bin/firefox-install-profile ] && /usr/bin/firefox-install-profile
[ -x /usr/local/bin/check-citrix-certs.sh ] && /usr/local/bin/check-citrix-certs.sh
[ -x /usr/bin/migrate-webapps ] && /usr/bin/migrate-webapps

# boot scripts
##############
/etc/init.d/rc S

# lock down /var for CTS   
########################   
chown root.adas /var/tmp   
chown root.adas /var/lock  
chmod 775 /var/tmp         
chmod 775 /var/lock        

chmod 666 /dev/socket/dbus 
chmod 666 /dev/null        

# runlevel 2 scripts       
####################       
/etc/init.d/rc 2           

cp /sdcard/*.lic /data/    
chmod 666 /data/*.lic
```

This is really strange, any ideas?

Comment: You should probably open it with a text editor and examine the content.

Comment: Are you trying to install Ubuntu in a android phone?? That nice!!

Comment: Why don't you just open the file with an editor and look what it does? I wouldn't be surprised if it has something to do with the Desktop mode of the Atrix that starts when you connect it with the Laptop Dock or the HD dock.

Comment: Yeah I've since found out that this file is run when you run the lapdock. Apparently it is actually a heavily modified version of Ubuntu. Interesting right?

Answer (score 1):

to run ubuntu.sh, your android does need to be rooted, and from the terminal emulator you must first grant super user privelage by executing the su command, then you can sh ubuntu.sh, and after it loads , it is running as a vnc server, in order to view, and manage ubuntu.sh you would need to use a vnc viewer and on the same device the ip address to connect would be 127.0.0.1 if I'm right, its been a while since ive done so myself since upgrading to android 4.0.4 ICS, which sacrifices performance to give me beauty.

Comment: I've given it superuser privileges, and I'm ready to run it, I'm just not sure what it does... Are you saying I would be running Ubuntu on my phone? What good would this do me, and why is it even there?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you're running the Atrix 4G, the phone that gets a whole new interface when it's docked

Looking at this, Ubuntu is that interface, which would explain tons of things, like why it's so slow

If you run the script without docking, you will need to run as root, so "su" and then you should see at the end a IP Adresas and a port, use a VNC app and access your phone's LAN IP via that port and you should see the Atrix Motorola dock environment, not everything may be working properly, but it should give you an idea of the script